# Stable computation of matrix expression $HQ(Q^THQ)^{-1}Q^TH$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be an $n \times n$ positive definite matrix, and let $Q$ be an $n \times m$ matrix with orthonormal columns, with $m \leq \sqrt n$. Then
$$ A = HQ(Q^THQ)^{-1}Q^TH$$
is a well-defined $n\times n$ matrix having rank at most $m$. If we let $$H^{1/2}Q = U\Sigma V^T$$
be a singular value decomposition of $H^{1/2}Q$, with $V$ being an orthogonal $m \times m$ matrix, then 
\begin{align*}Q^THQ &= (H^{1/2}Q)^TH^{1/2}Q \\
&= (U\Sigma V^T)^T U \Sigma V^T \\
&= V\Sigma U^TU\Sigma V^T\\
&= V\Sigma^2 V^T\end{align*}
and it follows that
\begin{align*}A &= HQ(Q^THQ)^{-1}Q^TH \\
&= H^{1/2}(H^{1/2}Q)(Q^THQ)^{-1}(H^{1/2}Q)^TH^{1/2}\\
&= H^{1/2}(U\Sigma V^T)(V\Sigma^2 V^T)^{-1}(U\Sigma V^T)^TH^{1/2}\\
&= H^{1/2}U\Sigma V^T V \Sigma^{-2} V^T V \Sigma U^T H^{1/2}\\
&= H^{1/2}U U^T H^{1/2}
\end{align*}
This shows that the definition of $A$ extends continuously to the case where $H$ is merely positive semidefinite; in other words, in the original definition of $A$ the matrix inverse $(Q^THQ)^{-1}$ creates only removable discontinuities.

**In this setting where $H$ is positive semidefinite but possibly singular, is there an efficient, numerically stable way 1) to compute a singular value decomposition of $A$, or 2) to compute matrix-vector products $Av$?** Assume that $H$ is not stored explicitly, but that there is an efficient algorithm for computing matrix-vector products $Hv$. By "efficient" I mean computing the singular value decomposition of $A$ in $O(nm^2)$ time or computing a matrix-vector product $Av$ in $O(mn)$, since this is the complexity we get using the numerically unstable original formula $A = HQ(Q^THQ)^{-1}Q^TH$. Computing $H^{1/2}$ explicitly is unsatisfactory since even storing this result would be $O(n^2)$ which is too slow.